# Почему вылетает ошибка can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

Я обучаю логистическую регрессию , мне нужно закодировать строковый параметр Embarked по
первой букве.

```
features_in = [ 'Embarked' ]
features_out = ['Survived']


train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', delimiter=',')
cabin= {}
a=0

for feature in features_in:
   test = test[test[feature].notna()]
   train = train[train[feature].notna()]
for index, row in train.iterrows():
  if (row["Embarked"][0] not in cabin.keys()):

       cabin[row["Embarked"][0]] = a
       train.loc[index, 'Embarked'] = a
       a+=1
  else:
       train.loc[index, 'Embarked'] =  cabin[row["Embarked"][0]]
class LogisticRegression(torch.nn.Module):
 def __init__(self):
   super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
   self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(len(features_in), len(features_out))

 def forward(self, x):
   y_hat = self.linear(x)
   return torch.sigmoid(y_hat)

x = train[features_in].to_numpy()  #
y = train[features_out].to_numpy()
x_torch = torch.from_numpy(x).type(torch.FloatTensor)
y_torch = torch.from_numpy(y).type(torch.FloatTensor).reshape(-1, 1)
model = LogisticRegression()
```

Вроде я кодирую все поля , но получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32
```

Ссылка на train.csv:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/126hYfrkzkP6X-ZLZSpremwohrSaSuvZ5/view?usp=sharing
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: Вручную такие вещи обычно не делают. Используйте готовый OHE https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Файл с данными, кстати, не даёт посмотреть: "Этот файл нельзя открыть, так как он нарушает Условия использования."